# Htaccess remove trash from end of URL using redirect 301

Tags: redirection, url, htaccess, trash

I need to remove "trash" from the end of the URL.

I have more than 1000 URLs with this word: "card link" at the end of the URL.

The URL before the word "card link" is dynamic.

URL example with the trash:

- `https://example.com/frases/f/como-fazer/Card%20link`
- `https://example.com/frases/f/just-now/Card%20link`
- `https://example.com/frases/f/mybag/Card%20link`

URL final:

- `https://example.com/frases/f/como-fazer/`
- `https://example.com/frases/f/just-now/`
- `https://example.com/frases/f/mybag/`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> https://example.com/frases/f/como-fazer/Card%20link
> ```

The `Card%20link` (aka "trash") that needs to be removed is at the end of the URL-path (not the query string as mentioned in the other answer).

You can remove this using mod_rewrite, near the top of the root `.htaccess` file.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+/)?Card\slink$ /$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* has already been %-decoded (ie. URL decoded) so we need to match against a literal *space*, not `%20` (an encoded *space*). In the above regex, the shorthand character class `\s` matches any whitespace character.

The regex `^(.+/)?Card\slink$` matches any URL-path that ends with `/card%20link` (case-insensitive), including requests that should otherwise be for the homepage (if that is a thing, eg. `example.com/Card%20link`).

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive if this already occurs elsewhere in the config file. (Although for readability, the `RewriteEngine` directive should appear just once at the top of the file.)

You should first test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues. And you will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Works ! i just remove the / before $1: RewriteRule ^(.+/)?Card\slink$ $1 [NC,R=301,L] Because the subdirectory.

Comment: @AdamoSantos Glad you got it working. Ah, so the `.htaccess` file is located in a subdirectory and you have defined a `RewriteBase` with the relevant subdirectory? (I had assumed your `.htaccess` file was located in the root directory.)

Comment: @AdamoSantos If this answered your question, then please mark it as "accepted" (tick/checkmark on the left below the voting arrows) to remove it from the unanswered question queue and to help other readers. Once you have 15+ rep then you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)